# What is the meaning of || in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at these lines of code from [here](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/plugins/sigma.parsers.cypher/sigma.parsers.cypher.js#L184-186):

```
    if (callback)
        callback(sig || graph);
```

I have never see vertical "or" bars in a javascript method call. What do they mean? Do they pass the "true" parameter (i.e. sig or graph)? Do they pass the defined parameter? I have never seen that syntax before.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is the logical OR operator in JS (and most other languages). It is [defined in the spec at 11.11](https://es5.github.io/#x11.11). As noted in the spec, expressions on either side will be evaluated first and the logical OR is [left-to-right associative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Note that evaluation of the operands follows standard [ToBoolean semantics from section 9.2](https://es5.github.io/#x9.2), so `[null, undefined, 0, '']` all count as falsy.

Unlike most languages, JS returns the left operand if it is truthy or the right operand otherwise. This behavior [has been covered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036171/proper-use-of) in a number of SO questions, but is worth noting as most languages simply return true or false. This behavior is often used to [provide default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642641/javascript-beginner-logical-or-and-empty-brackets) to otherwise undefined variables.

Comment: It doesn't return `false` if both are falsy; it returns the value of the right-hand side, whatever it may be (so, `0` maybe, or `""`).

Comment: @Pointy my mistake, fixed.

Comment: "Unlike most languages, JS returns the left operand if it is truthy or the right operand otherwise." is a little broad. This approach is fairly common among scripting languages with a concept of "truthiness", e.g. Python and Perl. Even Ruby has this behavior, though it's not as useful (because almost everything in Ruby is truthy, so the left-hand side must be coerced to boolean for the test, which means this only works for defaulting from `false` or `nil` to another value, not from arbitrary "falsy" objects like 0 values, empty sequences, etc.).

Answer (score 12):

The [Logical OR operator (`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) is an operator that returns its first or second operand depending on whether the first is truthy. A "truthy" value means anything other than `0`, `undefined`, `null`, `""`, or `false`.

This operator uses short-circuiting, meaning if the first expression is truthy, then the second expression is not evaluated and the first operand is returned immediately. This is akin to the [Logical AND operator (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND), which does the opposite: if the first operand is falsey, it returns it, otherwise it returns the second expression.

Comment: Can someone please explain what's wrong with my answer so I may improve it?

Comment: The logical operators do not always return a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

It means 'or' (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) So if(sig OR graph)

**BE CAREFUL** you can 'short circuit' your code using this.
example :

```
If (foo || foo2)
```

if foo is true, then JavaScript wont even test foo2 at all, it just skips it.

Answer (score 1):

It passes whichever evaluates as true, or `sig` if both are true.

Answer (score 0):

The double pipe (||) represents OR in JS. In simple words, either this or that is `True`. It requires any of the sides true to get a `True` result.

For example:

var x = 8;

var y = 'c';

x >= 8 || y === 'a'

The left side of the double pipe returns `True` where the right side is `False`. Thus, the result is `True`.

Answer (score -2):

The operator || means OR.

If either sig or graph are true or not null variables, callback function will receive a true argument.

Comment: This is not how JavaScript works, though it's true for some other languages (like Java).

Comment: My mistake. If the arguments are not boolean, the callback function will accept the first not null (or undefined) argument.