# JS: Null-Safe Array Concat

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Given:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = null
```

I need to:

`var c = [...a, ...b]`

.. but that does not work when `a` or `b` is null of course. So in this example `b` should just not be added, resulting in `c = [1, 2, 3]`. If both `a`and `b` are null (or undefined), the result should be [].

Are there any shorthands to avoid having to write two `if`-statements?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could make use of the [`||` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108466/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-javascript/30108494).

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = null

var c = [...a||[], ...b||[]]

console.log(c)
```

Comment: @HondaGuy not exactly sure what you want to say with that comment. If `b` is null then it is not placed in `c` because `...b||[]` evaluates to `...[]`  and this will result in no element be added to `c`. So how are your linked answers better regarding to the question of the OP?

Comment: My mistake. I made a mistake analyzing why I had found the other solution more useful in the situation that led me here. Comment removed. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

```
var c = [...(a || []), ...(b || [])]
```

This way if any array is null or undefined it will be replaced by an empty array

Answer (score 3):

**You can use filter**

```
var a = [1, 2]
var b = null
var c = [3, null, 4]

var d = []
d.concat(a,b,c).filter(item => item !== null) // [1, 2, 3, 4]

console.log("Array", d)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can validate and concat array like this using ternary operator**

```
    const a = [1,2,3,4,5];
    const b =  null;
    const c =  [6,7,8,9];
    const final = [...a ? a :[],...b ? b : [],...c ? c : []];
    console.log(final)
```

[Click here for code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbct05gd/1/)