# Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined on Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I shall start this question with, i'm a beginner for discord.js, and please help me!

My whole index.js is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client =  new Discord.Client();
const botsettings = require('./botsettings.json')

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!");
 });
client.on("message", async message =>{
    const playminecraftwithus = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'play-minecraft-with-us')
    if(playminecraftwithus.content.startsWith("IGN:")) {
        return; 
 } else {
   message.delete();
}
});

client.login(botsettings.token);
```

and the problem is in this block:

```
client.on("message", async message =>{
    const playminecraftwithus = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'play-minecraft-with-us')
    if(playminecraftwithus.content.startsWith("IGN:")) {
        return; 
 } else {
   message.delete();
}
});
```

but error message is like:

```
(node:13811) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined | discord.js
```

If you need anything else, please tell me!

Comment: it means `playminecraftwithus.content` is undefined - to debug, suggest you `console.log(playminecraftwithus)` to see what you are dealing with

Comment: `playminecraftwithus` is a `Channel`, and doesn't have the `content` property. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to type `message.content.startsWith()` instead of `playminecraftwithus.content.startsWith()`.

Answer (score 0):

`playminecraftwithus.content` is undefined.

undefined has no method `startsWith()`

if you want to avoid an error, you could convert to string and use it.

Try this: `(playminecraftwithus.content || "").startsWith()`

`||` means that when previous one is undefined use next. [more details on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108466/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-javascript)

Comment: There is no `content` property on `Channel` objects.

Comment: @김현진 Yes you're right. As like linoness10 said on comment, i do not know what is expected result for question. thus i fixed an error to use string method for undefined. Even we don't know the context neither what he want.