# toContain() with or options

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor

I have this code and I want to check that whether each element has either "Company" or "Individual".

This code fails. If the element has only "Company", jasmine looks for "Individual" as well. If the element has one of the options it should pass but it doesn't

```
$$('div.modal').then(function (list) {
            list.forEach(function (elm) {
                expect(elm.getText()).toContain('Company' || 'Individual');
            })
        })
```

Comment: if the element has "company" ,jasmine looks for "individual" as well
eg Expected 'Former (Company) to contain 'Individual'

Comment: I meant it fails

Comment: `'Company' || 'Individual'` is simply `'Company'`; the way it is used is like a Coalescing Operator so the first not null value is 'company'

Comment: @freedomn-m fixed the description

Comment: @Firewizz make it more clear please

Comment: You could just use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) like `.toMatch(/Company|Individual/)`

Comment: `.toContain(value)` where value = `'Company' || 'Individual'`  that's not company or individual, it's company || individual.   See [meaning of ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108466/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-javascript).  *Unlike most languages, JS returns the left operand if it is truthy* - a string is truthy, so returns the first string.  You need a different method, not .toContain()

Comment: I mean `null || false || "" || "Valid"` just returns valid. Use Reyno's solution with regex to solve multiple cases

Comment: @Reyno 's solution didnt work.

Comment: `["Individual", "Company", "Company", "Individual", "exclude"].flatMap(e=> e.match(/Company|Individual/g))` I tested it the plain javascript way but that should work. No mathes return null

Comment: for me `.toMatch(/Company || Individual/) ` worked